# How to use temporary files and replace the input when using ffmpeg in batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file, video, ffmpeg

#### What I did so far:

I learned with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38162168/12194725) that I can use [negative mapping](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options) to remove unwanted streams (extra audio, subtitles) from my video files.

I them proceeded to apply it to a few dozen files in a folder using a simple `for /r` loop on Windows' cmd. Since I thought this process as some kind of trim, I didn't care about my original files and wanted ffmpeg to replace them, which of course it cannot.

I tried to search a bit further and find ways to work around this issue without simply using a new destination an manually replacing files afterwards, but had no luck.

However a lot of my findings seemed to indicate that ffmpeg has capabilities to use external temporary files for some of it's functions, even though I couldn't really find more onto it.

#### What I want to do:

So is there any way that I can make ffmpeg remove those extra streams and them replace the original file somehow. I'll also be needing to use this to multiple file, by I don't think this would be a big issue...

I really need this to be done with ffmpeg, as learning the tool to it's full extent is a long-therm goal of mine and I want to keep working on that curve, but as for batch/cmd, I prefer it because I haven't properly learned a programming language yet (even if I often meddle with a few), but I would be happy to use suggestions of any kind for handling ffmpeg!

Thank you!

Comment: As it is right now, your question is off topic.  Please take the [tour]. Learn [ask] and please also read [mcve].

Comment: I reread those, but I still don't understand why it's off-topic. I didn't post what I'm currently using because it's not supposed to be even a partial solution, my question is centered about what is a central "limitation" of ffmpeg and ways to workaround it.

Nevertheless, my previous writing may have been confusing, so please tell me if so.

The code I currently use is

`for /r %i in (*) do ffmpeg -i "%~fi" -map 0 -map -0:a:2 -c copy D:\Folder\%~i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Not possible with `ffmpeg` alone

`ffmpeg` can't do in-place file changes.

The output must be a new file.

However, deleting/removing/replacing to original file with the new file should be trivial in your batch script.

> I saw some vague references while searching and also stumbled upon the cache protocol and `-hls_flags temp_file`

The [cache protocol](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#cache) allows some limited seeking during playback of live inputs. `-hls_flags temp_file` is only usable with the [HLS muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#hls-2) and creates a file named `filename.tmp` which is then renamed once the active segment completes. Neither are usable for what you want to do.

Comment: Well, that is what I wanted help with... And if ffmpeg's temp file functionality can be used for that, I believe it would be the most economic way of doing it.

Comment: @FabioFreitas What do you mean by "ffmpeg's temp file functionality"?

Comment: If it doesn't ring a bell to you, it's very much likely I mistaken things. I saw some vague references while searching and also stumbled upon [these](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#cache) two [entries](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Options-43) on the documentation. But I still don't understand ffmpeg if I don't find a perfectly explained answer here, that's why I made such a vague assumption.

Comment: @FabioFreitas The cache protocol allows some limited seeking during playback of live inputs. `-hls_flags temp_file` is only usable with the HLS muxer and creates a file named `filename.tmp` which is then renamed once the active segment completes. Neither are usable for what you want to do. You're just going to have to output to a new file and then replace the old one.

Comment: Okay, that settles it, thank you. Could you add this info to your answer?