# FFMPEG fails while processing MOV files

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, mpeg-dash, mov

I'm trying to convert video files to DASH format. All videos work great **except MOV** videos.

I'm using the following command:

```
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -y -i /path/to/mov/video.mov -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -bf 1 -keyint_min 25 -g 250 -sc_threshold 40 -use_timeline 1 -use_template 1 -init_seg_name 'video_init_$RepresentationID$.$ext$' -media_seg_name 'video_chunk_$RepresentationID$_$Number%05d$.$ext$' -seg_duration 10 -hls_playlist 0 -f dash -adaptation_sets -0:s -map 0 -s:v:0 854x480 -b:v:0 750k -strict -2 -threads 12 /output/path/video.mpd
```

I get the error:

- `Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument ... Error initializing output stream 0:1`

The full command output is:

```
ffmpeg version 4.3.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
built with Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)
configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.3.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-videotoolbox --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack
libavutil 56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
libavcodec 58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
libavformat 58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
libavdevice 58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
libavfilter 7. 85.100 / 7. 85.100
libavresample 4. 0. 0 / 4. 0. 0
libswscale 5. 7.100 / 5. 7.100
libswresample 3. 7.100 / 3. 7.100
libpostproc 55. 7.100 / 55. 7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/path/to/file.mov':
Metadata:
major_brand : qt
minor_version : 0
compatible_brands: qt
creation_time : 2020-09-21T09:45:27.000000Z
com.apple.quicktime.make: Apple
com.apple.quicktime.model: iPhone 7
com.apple.quicktime.software: 13.4.1
com.apple.quicktime.creationdate: 2020-06-15T11:59:36+0200
com.apple.photos.originating.signature: AXfhZgW4nrUdSusOMUuJRarfxD7R
Duration: 00:01:13.40, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 10616 kb/s
Stream #0:0(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 96 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
creation_time : 2020-09-21T09:45:27.000000Z
handler_name : Core Media Audio
Stream #0:1(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 10514 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc (default)
Metadata:
creation_time : 2020-09-21T09:45:27.000000Z
handler_name : Core Media Video
encoder : H.264
Stream #0:2(und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D) (default)
Metadata:
creation_time : 2020-09-21T09:45:27.000000Z
handler_name : Core Media Metadata
Stream #0:3(und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 0 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
creation_time : 2020-09-21T09:45:27.000000Z
handler_name : Core Media Metadata
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Stream #0:2 -> #0:2 (copy)
Stream #0:3 -> #0:3 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x7f7f2600e000] using SAR=1280/1281
[libx264 @ 0x7f7f2600e000] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x7f7f2600e000] profile High, level 3.1, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x7f7f2600e000] 264 - core 160 r3011 cde9a93 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2020 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=1 b_pyramid=0 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=abr mbtree=1 bitrate=750 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:1 --
[aac @ 0x7f7f2600c000] Qavg: 880.111
[aac @ 0x7f7f2600c000] 2 frames left in the queue on closing
[libx264 @ 0x7f7f2600e000] final ratefactor: 28.97
Conversion failed!
```

```
Stream #0:2 -> #0:2 (copy)
Stream #0:3 -> #0:3 (copy)
```

I guess the problem is that the file contains two not audio/video streams:
I can not find a way to exclude or ignore or copy without processing those last two streams (#2 and #3).

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'IMG_3599.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2020-09-21T09:45:27.000000Z
    com.apple.quicktime.make: Apple
    com.apple.quicktime.model: iPhone 7
    com.apple.quicktime.software: 13.4.1
    com.apple.quicktime.creationdate: 2020-06-15T11:59:36+0200
    com.apple.photos.originating.signature: AXfhZgW4nrUdSusOMUuJRarfxD7R
  Duration: 00:01:13.40, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 10616 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 96 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-09-21T09:45:27.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
    Stream #0:1(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 10514 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-09-21T09:45:27.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      encoder         : H.264
    Stream #0:2(und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D) (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-09-21T09:45:27.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Metadata
    Stream #0:3(und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-09-21T09:45:27.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Metadata
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this problem I had to remove all streams from the video file.

This answer helps me to build the proper ffmpeg command to prepare video file before processing it by the original command https://stackoverflow.com/a/38162168/10561527

Answer (score 0):

No need to prepare the file beforehand.

## Only map video and audio

You are using `-map 0` which includes **all** streams. I doubt the DASH muxer works with other stream types such as data (streams `#0:2` & `#0:3` in your example), subtitles, and attachments.

Change `-map 0` to `-map 0:v -map 0:a` to make sure only video and audio are included.

## Your -adaptation_sets is wrong

Remove this option and use the default, or read the [FFmpeg DASH muxer documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#dash) to modify it.