# How to delete audio stream from video using Ffmpeg in c++

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, libav

I want to delete audio stream from video and get the only video stream. But, when I search on google could not find any tutorial except decoding. Is there a way to delete a specific stream from video.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly *delete* a stream from a file. You can, however, write a new file that contains all but one (or more) streams of the original file, which can be done without decoding and encoding the streams.

For this purpose, you can use [libavformat](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.1/group__libavf.html), which is part of ffmpeg. You first have to demux the video file, which gives you *packages* that contain the encoded data for each stream inside the container. Then, you write (mux) these packages into a new video container. Take a look at the [remuxing example](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.1/remuxing_8c-example.html) for details.

Note, however, you can get the same result, by calling the `ffmpeg` program and passing it the apropriate parameters, which is probably easier [[SO1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38161697/how-to-remove-one-track-from-video-file-using-ffmpeg)].

Comment: I see, thank you. I have to do that process in c++.